# In GAE how do you *stop* running your app?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm on Eclipse (Helios) using GAE SDK 1.5.2, etc. (Just updated everything, today.)

"In the old days..." (earlier SDKs), when I ran/debug my app locally, it would create an app on my machine (Mac, OS-X 10.6.latest) and, when I wanted to quit it, I would just CMD-Q that app.

Now, when I launch the app, it appears to run as a sub-process of Eclipse (assumption on my part -- I can't find any separate app that's running), and I can't seem to figure out how to quit the app.

The specific problem I'm having is, after I change something and select **Run -> Debug as... -> Web Application** the 2nd time, I get "address in use" socket-binding error.

```
[ERROR] Unable to bind socket on port 9997 -- is another session active?
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

I suspect that, yes, another session IS active (the one I started just 2 minutes ago!), and my question is: how do I stop that session?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look in the debug window you'll see your running processes.  Just select one, right click and 'Terminate':

[image: Terminate option]

Comment: Ha!  Once I hunted around and figured out how to add the Debug View to my perspective, this worked perfectly!  (Yes, I could switch to debug perspective, but I really just want to use my perspective (Java) with the addition of a debug view :)   Thanks!

Comment: (As you can probably tell, Eclipse is not my native IDE... ;)

Comment: You should also just be able to press the 'stop' button in the console window down the bottom.