# How to stop project that is already running

Tags: eclipse

It says app is already running, but I see no big red button to stop it.  I'm assuming it the 'Terminate' button. Its greyed out.

[image]

EDIT:
screenshot after I reopened eclipse and hit big green arrow(RUN)

[image]

And after it ran:
[image]

no red button while it was running.

Comment: What's this about heap stack errors in the errors view?

Comment: Actually that's a huge issue I'm having with this app.  But in order to post a question about THAT issue I'm having THIS issue.  I hate eclipse.

Comment: If you close eclipse and restart by running as administrator, does the problem still happen?

Comment: Tried that.  After I run this project I have to wait until it crashes because I can't terminate it.  I can't right click the project and terminate.

Comment: If you try and create a blank, new project what happens?

Comment: ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Its a while since I used eclipse, but I believe you can right click on the elements in the debug window and choose terminate from there.

There is a screen shot in [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6861871/97614) which might help

Comment: IT greyed out.  But the green arrow button(I assume is start) states that the app is running ...when I hover mouse ove rit.

Comment: Yeah just looked at the screen shot more closely.  Seems that there were some errors (look at red text in console window).  I don't believe the app is running, regardless of that tooltip message.

Comment: can you click the big green start button again?

Comment: Saw the screenshot...mine are all greyed out.\

Comment: no, there is one nearer the middle which isn't, next to the debug one.  It has a drop down next to it.  I seem to remember starting the app using that.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the debug launches name in the debug view and selecting 'Terminate and Disconnect'.

Is that available for selection in your state (it should be).

Comment: That's what I keep saying....I've tried that and eveything is greyed out.  I can't terminate.